# Click through full height element to empty space to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I want to remove `.visible` class when I click inside of the unfilled space of a full-height header.**

Inside of the header I have `.container` that doesn't have full height.

When I click on the container or its links, it shouldn't remove the class but when I click on remaining space below container it should remove the class.

Is this possible with the given HTML and CSS?

https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/EeNoqR

```js
$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('visible');
});
$('.visible *:not(.container)').click(function() {
  alert('clicked the outside');
  $('body').removeClass('visible');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to keep the same HTML and CSS?

Comment: @AndreaLigios It would be preferrable, unless changed with js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a `click` event to the `<header>`, another click event to its inner `<div>`, and stop the propagation of the event so that only the more specific one (the div) will be executed:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.button', function(){
      $('body').toggleClass('visible');
    });
    $('header').click(function() {
      alert('clicked outside the container');
      $('body').removeClass('visible');
      return false; 
    });
  $('.container').click(function(e){
    alert ('clicked inside the container');
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body.visible header {
  display:block;
}
header {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;    
}
.container {  
  background: #ccc;
  padding:30px;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
a {
  display:block;
}
.button {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:9999;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="button">Button</div>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">asd</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">asdas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">asdsa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">asdasda</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind click to all elements and check if body has class in it:

```
$('body *:not(.container)').click(function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('visible')){
      alert('clicked the outside');
      $('body').removeClass('visible');
      return false;
    }
});
```